# Ambiguous Syntax

Tags: c++, ambiguity

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int MYINT;

int main() 
{ 
    int y = MYINT();                     // As expected, y = 0; value initialization
    cout << MYINT();                     // Error
    cout << sizeof(MYINT());             // Error
}
```

Why the last two lines in the main function before the closing brace give error? Why is the expression MYINT() treated differently in different contexts? Any Standard reference will be helpful.

Comment: could you show the declaration of MYINT?

Comment: What is `MYINT()` ?  I would help us answer your question.

Comment: Please post how the MYINT() macro is defined. Cannot help without that.

Comment: @Anders K.: He has: `typedef int MYINT;`

Comment: What error? Where's `cout` defined?

Comment: @Charles Bailey, he has probably edited the question. I also didn't see this typedef before.

Comment: Yes friends, I did take care of all the comments

Comment: @rhino: It wasn't highlighted correctly before, but it was there when I first read the question.

Comment: The second line compiles for me (gcc4.1.2), as I believe it should. Which compiler are you using, and what are the errors?

Comment: @chubsdad see how giving enough info works wonders? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any error for the `cout << MYINT();` line. However I see `invalid application of 'sizeof' to a function type` for the `cout << sizeof(MYINT());` line. The problem is the `()` around `MYINT()`. The C++ standard says this about `sizeof` and how it is parsed:

```
sizeof unary-expression
sizeof ( type-id )
```

There is a parsing ambiguity between `sizeof unary-expression` and `sizeof ( type-id )`. It is resolved by using longer match. It parses `sizeof (MYINT())` as `sizeof ( type-id )`, `MYINT()` is a function type and thus you see the error.

Answer (score 8):

`MYINT()` can, depending on context, be interpreted as an expression of type `MYINT`, or a specifier of a function type taking no arguments and returning `MYINT`.
In some situations, where either an expression or a type specifier is valid, this gives an ambiguity; this is resolved by interpreting it as a type specifier if possible (**EDIT**: C++03 8.2/2, if you want a Standard reference).

`sizeof` can take either an expression, or a parenthesised type specifier, as it's argument, giving this ambiguity. So here `MYINT()` is interpreted as a type specifier; then you get an error, since `sizeof` can't be applied to a function type.

**EDIT:** You can fix the error by removing the parentheses so it will be interpreted as an expression (`sizeof MYINT()`), adding extra parentheses so it isn't a valid type specifier (`sizeof((MYINT()))`), or changing it to the correct type (`sizeof(MYINT)`).

`cout << MYINT()` is unambiguous, so there should be no error, and indeed there isn't on my compiler. What is the error, and what is your compiler?

Comment: +1. May be worthwhile to show a work around. One such is to say `sizeof MYINT()` or `sizeof((MYINT()))`

Comment: Indeed there is no error on cout << MYINT() on a second confirmation on my system as well!. Sorry for the misleading info

Answer (score 6):

If your `MINTINT` is `typedef int MYINT` then `MYINT()` is not a function but is `int()` which is a default initialization, equivallent to `int y = 0` or `int y = int(0)`.

Your second line, ie `cout << MYINT()` compiles correctly for me with `g++ -Wall -ansi -pedantic` for the same reason.

But `g++` will complain for the `sizeof` with the following error `error: invalid application of "sizeof" to a function type` because it interprets `MYINT()` as "a call to a default constructor for int" (**EDIT**: this is not correct) "a function type returning MYINT which is not allowed" (**EDIT**: this is the correct answer, see Mike's). But this a nothing to do with the `typedef`.

Summary:

```
#include <iostream>
typedef int myint;
int main()
{
int y = myint();
int z = myint(0);
std::cout << y << z; // Will output 0 0
std::cout << std::endl << myint(0) << myint(); // Will output 0 0
std::cout << sizeof(int()); // The error is here; same with sizeof(myint())
}
```

**Edit (again)**

As said in the comment is the `cout` lines doesn't work for you, this is because you probably forgot to `include <iostream>`.

**Edit**
Look also the answer of Mike Seymour for an explanation of the ambiguity with `sizeof`.

Comment: You need to explain why a value initialized temporary isn't valid (if it isn't) in the other two lines.

Comment: Why sizeof interpret int() as a function, but not a temporary valuable?

Comment: See the answer of Mike Seymour.

Comment: @Dbger: When there is an ambiguity over whether something is an expression or a type specifier, it will be interpreted as a type specifier (in this case, a function type).

Comment: "The resolution is that any construct that could possibly be a type-id in its syntactic context shall be considered as type-id" ---- from C++ standard, that it because type-id is of high priority

Comment: @Mike Seymour sorry, I didn't notice your reply first. That is how C++ defined, thanks.

Comment: So cout << sizeof(MYINT(1)) won't be a problem as it doesn't like an type specifier anymore

Comment: Ints do not have a "default constructor". So this is a wrong answer, but delegates to the correct answer by @Mike. Yet, it's upvoted to +7 while @Mike's answer is at +3. Weird!

Comment: Mike is correct, that's why I mentioned his answer, third Mike's answer came after mine, that's why I guess I have more upvotes... To be completely fair I corrected the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

```
// OK. Implicit conversion to int.
int y = MYINT();          

// OK. Implicit conversion again. Which compiler do you use?
cout << MYINT();          

// Invalid. Tries to get size of a function that returns MYINT,
// because sizeof expects a type-id and according to 8.2/2,
// which is forbidden according to the C++ Standard 5.3.3/1
cout << sizeof(MYINT());  
// Do you want this instead?
cout << sizeof(MYINT);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why the last two lines in the main function before the closing brace give error?

`cout << MYINT();` doesn't work because `cout` is not defined. Once you do `#include <iostream>` and `using std::cout`, it will work fine.

`sizeof(MYINT())` does indeed not work, but `sizeof(int())` doesn't work either, so that's to be expected. `sizeof(MYINT)` will work just fine.

> Why is the expression MYINT() treated differently in different contexts?

It's not. In every case `MYINT()` behaves exactly like `int()`.

Comment: +1 for there is no need to define MYINT to show the same results